# Plotly Express graph legend in Python has only one item displayed, how to fix it?

Tags: plotly-express

Plotly express graph shows only one item in legend

Developed a code to draw the graph using plotly express.

```
width = 900
height = 400

fig = px.line(logger,
    x=logger.index,
    y='LEVEL',
    title='NWHSA Borehole Data Analysis',
    width=width,
    height=height
)
fig.add_scatter(x=logger.index, 
    y=logger['TEMPERATURE'],
    mode='lines',
    name='Temperature',
    yaxis='y2'
)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title='Month',
    yaxis_title = 'Water level (metres bgl)',
    yaxis=dict(
            autorange="reversed"),
    yaxis2=dict(
            title=("Temperature (°C)"),
            overlaying="y",
            side="right"
    ),
    legend=dict(
                orientation='h',
                yanchor="bottom",
                y=1.02,
                xanchor="center",
                x=0.5,
                itemsizing='constant',
                itemwidth=30
    )
)
         
fig.show()
```

Data - part
LEVEL   TEMPERATURE
DateTime
2022-10-14 18:00:00     16.8905     26.319
2022-10-15 06:00:00     16.0754     26.321
2022-10-15 18:00:00     15.4648     26.325
2022-10-16 06:00:00     15.5902     26.325
2022-10-16 18:00:00     15.5039     26.326
2022-10-17 06:00:00     15.3815     26.326
2022-10-17 18:00:00     15.0869     26.330
2022-10-18 06:00:00     14.8969     26.330
2022-10-18 18:00:00     14.6918     26.333
2022-10-19 06:00:00     14.6748     26.336

[image: results of the above code]